# Animated gifs lagging in html

Tags: python, html, animation, gif, lag

I am wanting to make gifs in python, then put them on a website using HTML (note today is my first day of using HTML). The gifs being produced are fairly large (around 18MB), and are very choppy when I load my HTML page in both Chrome and Firefox.

To save my gifs in Python I am doing the following.

```
# save animation
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=20, repeat_delay=0)
writer1 = animation.PillowWriter(fps=600)
ani.save("simpPendApprox10.gif",writer=writer1)
show()
```

I am making pendulum simulations, so the fps is very high to make the period of my animation equal to the period I would expect from a physical pendulum with the same parameters.

To call this in my HTML file I do the following

```
<img src="../images/simpPendApprox10.gif" alt="simpPendAnimation">
```

Is there a way to fix the choppiness? I am sure decreasing the size of the gif is a good start, but even after compressing my gif to only be 1MB, I still get the choppiness. I am not sure how to decrease the size more than that.

I could decrease the step size in my simulations, so I would have less frames and could decrease the FPS. But one of my goals on the site is to point out the difference in outcome when using different step sizes with different algorithms to solve the same problem.

Comment: You could consider dropping every second frame (or keeping every tenth frame) or something like that. 600fps is way too high. There shouldn't be any difference visible if the display refresh rate is 60Hz 

Comment: That is a good idea, and a good point about the refresh rate. It still is not quite as smooth as I would like, but much less choppy than it was. I will keep playing around with it and see if I can optimize it more. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. To my understanding, there shouldn't be a difference between 60 and 600fps, so just drop every frame except every tenth frame and the difference should be unnoticable 